# Bash on Snow Leopard doesn't obey terminal colours

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, bash, terminal.app

With the new version of Snow Leopard, OS X upgraded the bash version to `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`.

Now, my `.bashrc` sets the following settings:

```
# Colors
export TERM=xterm-color
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto' GREP_COLOR='1;32'
export CLICOLOR=1 
export LSCOLORS=ExGxFxDxCxHxHxCbCeEbEb

# Setup some colors to use later in interactive shell or scripts
export COLOR_NC='\e[0m' # No Color
export COLOR_WHITE='\e[1;37m'
export COLOR_BLACK='\e[0;30m'
export COLOR_BLUE='\e[0;34m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
export COLOR_GREEN='\e[0;32m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
export COLOR_CYAN='\e[0;36m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
export COLOR_RED='\e[0;31m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_RED='\e[1;31m'
export COLOR_PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE='\e[1;35m'
export COLOR_BROWN='\e[0;33m'
export COLOR_YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
export COLOR_GRAY='\e[1;30m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY='\e[0;37m'
```

The colours are used later on for output. This used to work in previous version of OSX but now my output not cooperating.

### Some ideas that have not worked.

- Switching Terminal.app from 64-bit to 32-bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was actually much simpler. Rather than using `\e` for the escape character, use `\033` instead. So it goes from

```
export COLOR_NC='\e[0m' # No Color
export COLOR_WHITE='\e[1;37m'
export COLOR_BLACK='\e[0;30m'
export COLOR_BLUE='\e[0;34m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
export COLOR_GREEN='\e[0;32m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
export COLOR_CYAN='\e[0;36m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
export COLOR_RED='\e[0;31m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_RED='\e[1;31m'
export COLOR_PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE='\e[1;35m'
export COLOR_BROWN='\e[0;33m'
export COLOR_YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
export COLOR_GRAY='\e[1;30m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY='\e[0;37m'
```

to:

```
# Setup some colors to use later in interactive shell or scripts
export COLOR_NC='\033[0m' # No Color
export COLOR_WHITE='\033[1;37m'
export COLOR_BLACK='\033[0;30m'
export COLOR_BLUE='\033[0;34m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE='\033[1;34m'
export COLOR_GREEN='\033[0;32m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN='\033[1;32m'
export COLOR_CYAN='\033[0;36m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
export COLOR_RED='\033[0;31m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_RED='\033[1;31m'
export COLOR_PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE='\033[1;35m'
export COLOR_BROWN='\033[0;33m'
export COLOR_YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
export COLOR_GRAY='\033[1;30m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY='\033[0;37m'
```

Comment: karbassi Thanks so much! I've been looking for a fix all day long.

Another solution would be to use zsh instead :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

My Terminal is showing colours.

Try using something like:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

And see if the colours appear.

Answer (score 1):

Since the colors are non-printable, using `\[` & `\]` at either end will prevent backspacing and line-wrapping from breaking.

```
export COLOR_NC='\[\033[0m\]' # No Color
export COLOR_WHITE='\[\033[1;37m\]'
export COLOR_BLACK='\[\033[0;30m\]'
export COLOR_BLUE='\[\033[0;34m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE='\[\033[1;34m\]'
export COLOR_GREEN='\[\033[0;32m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN='\[\033[1;32m\]'
export COLOR_CYAN='\[\033[0;36m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN='\[\033[1;36m\]'
export COLOR_RED='\[\033[0;31m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_RED='\[\033[1;31m\]'
export COLOR_PURPLE='\[\033[0;35m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE='\[\033[1;35m\]'
export COLOR_BROWN='\[\033[0;33m\]'
export COLOR_YELLOW='\[\033[1;33m\]'
export COLOR_GRAY='\[\033[1;30m\]'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY='\[\033[0;37m\]'
```